# Alphabet Soup - They give me the directions to a grid and I must return the whole letters in that direction (Python)

Tags: python

Words can be horizontal, vertical, or diagonal in the alphabet soup. [image that explains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEzOv.jpg)

I must create a function called gera_cadeia_fila, where there is given me 3 arguments: a grid, inicial position and direction.
I must give the letters from the starting position to the end position, respecting the given direction.
I'm a begginer and I'm so confused. Don't even know how to return it and the break won't work in the while loop.
This is what i have so far. I know it's maybe not even close of what I have to do. 
The other functions I have to keep them that way, it's part of the homework. Only the function gera_cadeia_fila isn't working. That's the one I need help with.
Can someone help me or advise the best way to do this? Thanks

```
grelha1= ["PIGATOS", 
          "ANRBKFD", 
          "TMCAOXA", 
          "OOBBYQU", 
          "MACOUIV", 
          "EEJMIWL"]


def proxima_pos(pos, dire):
    return (pos[0] + dire[0], pos[1] + dire[1]) #sums position and direction, eg. >>> proxima_pos((1, 2), (1, 0)) >>> (2,2)

def dimensions_grelha(grelha):
    return (len(grelha), len(grelha[0])) #gives me the dimension of line and column of grelha1

def gera_cadeia_fila(grelha, pos_start, dire): #grelha1, position where the word strats, directions it must follow

    new= ()

    dimensions = dimensions_grelha(grelha) 

    dimension_max_line= dimensions[0]
    dimension_max_column= dimensions[1]

    position_inicial_line= pos_start[0]
    position_inicial_column= pos_strat[1] 

    while position_inicial_line <= dimension_max_line and position_inicial_column <= dimension_max_column:

        new= (proxima_pos(pos_start, dire))

        if (new[0] > dimension_max_line or new[1] > dimension_max_colum):
        break

    return ???

#example of what the function must do:
>>> gera_cadeia_fila(grelha1, (1, 0), (0, 1))
’ANRBKFD’
>>> gera_cadeia_fila(grelha1, (0, 5), (1, 0))
’OFXQIW’
>>> gera_cadeia_fila(grelha1, (2, 0), (1, 1))
’TOCM’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have all the mechanism you need -- you just need to deploy it.  The two pieces you're missing are collecting letters as you move through the matrix and updating your current position from your update function:

```
grelha1 = [
    "PIGATOS",
    "ANRBKFD",
    "TMCAOXA",
    "OOBBYQU",
    "MACOUIV",
    "EEJMIWL"
]

def proxima_pos(pos, dire):
    """ sums position and direction, eg. >>> proxima_pos((1, 2), (1, 0)) >>> (2, 2) """

    return pos[0] + dire[0], pos[1] + dire[1]

def dimensions_grelha(grelha):
    """ gives the dimension of line and column of grelha """

    return len(grelha), len(grelha[0])

def gera_cadeia_fila(grelha, pos_start, dire):

    letters = ""

    dimension_max_line, dimension_max_column = dimensions_grelha(grelha)

    position_line, position_column = pos_start

    while position_line < dimension_max_line and position_column < dimension_max_column:

        letters += grelha1[position_line][position_column]

        position_line, position_column = proxima_pos((position_line, position_column), dire)

    return letters

print(gera_cadeia_fila(grelha1, (1, 0), (0, 1)))  # ’ANRBKFD’
print(gera_cadeia_fila(grelha1, (0, 5), (1, 0)))  # ’OFXQIW’
print(gera_cadeia_fila(grelha1, (2, 0), (1, 1)))  # ’TOCM’
```